# jCarousel dynamic content loading via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im try make a slider and load data dynamically from a php file, im get image from database but i have problem now to link this image...

Here is my php file **ajax_php.php**

```
// Array indexes are 0-based, jCarousel positions are 1-based.
$first = max(0, intval($_GET['first']) - 1);
$last  = max($first + 1, intval($_GET['last']) - 1);
$length = $last - $first + 1;
// ---
require_once('../../includes/config.php');
error_reporting(0);
mysql_connect($conf['host'], $conf['user'], $conf['pass']);
mysql_select_db($conf['name']);
$getUser = "SELECT * FROM sitex WHERE img_i!='images/img_i.jpg' ORDER BY `sitex`.`likes` DESC LIMIT 35";
$res = mysql_query($getUser) or die();

$images = array();

while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($res))) {
    $images[] = '/images/'.$row['img_i'].'';
}

$total    = count($images);
$selected = array_slice($images, $first, $length);

// ---

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo '<data>';

echo '  <total>' . $total . '</total>';
foreach ($selected as $img) {
    echo '<image>' . $img . '</image>';
} 
echo '</data>';
```

And here is js

```
function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state)
{
    // Check if the requested items already exist
    if (carousel.has(carousel.first, carousel.last)) {
        return;
    }

    jQuery.get(
        'ajax_php.php',
        {
            first: carousel.first,
            last: carousel.last
        },
        function(xml) {
            mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, carousel.first, carousel.last, xml);
        },
        'xml'
    );
};

function mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, first, last, xml)
{

     // Set the size of the carousel
    carousel.size(parseInt(jQuery('total', xml).text()));

    jQuery('image', xml).each(function(i) {
        carousel.add(first + i, mycarousel_getItemHTML(jQuery(this).text()));

    });
};


function mycarousel_getItemHTML(url)

{ 
    return '<img src="' + url + '" width="75" height="75" alt="" />';
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#futuredbc').jcarousel({

  easing: 'BounceEaseOut',
         itemVisibleOutCallback: {onAfterAnimation: function(carousel, item, i, state, evt) { carousel.remove(i); }},
        itemLoadCallback: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback
    });
});
```

This method back me result like

```
<img width="75" height="75" alt="" src="img.jpg">
```

But i need to make a linked image like

```
<a href="http://site.com/548"><img width="75" height="75" alt="" src="img.jpg"></a>
```

So site.com/**548** it'a i ID and i can get it from database `'.$row['id'].'` but i dont know how to make js and link result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (without adding functions to resolve another XML tags (`<bla>`)) is just
to add the ID to the value of the `image xml tag` and using a `delimiter` , we will `split` the id out of the url.

Add the `row ID` to the array:

```
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($res))) {
    $images[] = array('id' => $row['id'] , 'src' => '/images/'.$row['img_i'].'');
}
```

print it to the XML:

```
foreach ($selected as $img) {
    echo '<image>' . $img['src'] . '|||'.$img['id'].'</image>';
}
```

And then , repalce:

```
return '<img src="' + url + '" width="75" height="75" alt="" />';
```

With:

```
var tmp = url.split('|||');

return '<a href="www.site.com/'+ tmp[1] +'"><img src="' + tmp[0] + '" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></a>';
```

Should work. 
Otherwise , comment and i'll fix it.

Comment: Hmm but can`t work with 

    echo '<image>' . $img['src'] . '|||'.$img['id'].'</image>';
Have error now

Comment: Updated my answer.take a look at the first part now.